# I have a problem with the file manager, Nautilus, crashing within seconds of opening it

Tags: nautilus, dependencies

When I click the files icon the file manager window opens but closes at once.
Running nautilus from the terminal  - the same thing happens, and I get the following:
" Segmentation fault (core dumped) "

Then I ran Sudo nautilus - the same outcome except that the terminal report is:
"  ** (nautilus:23320): WARNING **: 18:37:28.928: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory

** (nautilus:23320): WARNING **: 18:37:28.929: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory
Segmentation fault "

I now attempted to remove and reinstall nautilus but failed at the first step.
On entering "Sudo apt-get remove nautilus", the terminal response was :

" Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
gsettings-desktop-schemas : Breaks: mutter (< 3.31.4) but 3.28.4+git20200505-0ubuntu18.04.2 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.  ""

So I now don't know what to do, and some suggestions would be much appreciated

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.5

Comment: The warning about bookmarks is not important. In order to diagnose this you need to launch a debugger. Run `gdb nautilus`, and when the command prompt `(gdb)` appears, enter `r`. After the crash occurs, type `bt full` and copy the trace to a pastebin and link it.